# Let $A$ be the $2\times 2$ matrix representing the reflection in the line $y=2x$. What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, reflection

> Let $A$ be the $2\times 2$ matrix representing the reflection in the line $y=2x$. Are the eigenvalues of $A$
>
> (a) $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=0$
>
> (b) $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=0$
>
> (c) $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=-1$
>
> (d) None of the above?

Hello, I know how to calculate Eigen values when giving a matrix, but I'm not sure what this question means exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you know how to write the matrix representation of this reflection? If you do that, then you can just find the eigenvalues of that matrix.

Comment: Draw a picture and look for some vectors (pictorially) which are transformed into a scalar multiple of themselves. What are those scalars for such vectors? If that's too weird, do it for reflection in the x-axis first.